# Using Mocks to Substitute Word Doc in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

can some one please provide an example of how would one go about
swapping out a Word document wit Mocks object (for testing scenario). My application uses Word document for populating template fields (in the doc) and also reading values from those fields as well, so it would be great to see an example of how to do that

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a wrapper class for the needed word document functionality (template fields, path, name etc.). Extract an interface and there you have it: Nice injectable and mockable stuff :-) Sorry, but I haven't got time for code example at this point. It is pretty straight forward though.

Answer (score 0):

You should include [`moq`](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) in your project and then mock out the interfaces, for example:

```
var mockDocument = new Mock<Document>();
```

before passing those interfaces to your objects that manages the word document.